# Imagen en subitem de ListView C#

Tags: c#, listview

Buen día a todos,

Escribo para saber si alguien me puede ayudar.

Tengo un listview que se carga de acuerdo con una consulta SQL, puedo cargar los string sin ningún inconveniente en la primera y segunda columna.  La tercera (subitem) debe cargar una imagen que esta en el equipo local en formato jpg y este es mi inconveniente, no puedo cargar la imagen.

Esto trabajando en C# - Windows Forms - Framework 3.5

Esto es lo que tengo de código

```
listView1.Clear();
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.GridLines = true;
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
listView1.Columns.Add("Persona", 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Id", 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Mail", 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left); //Columna de Imagen AQUI
ImageList image1 = new ImageList();
image1.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("C:\\CXN\\Email.jpg"));

//Query de Consulta AQUI

while (Lectura_Reader.Read() == true)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
    {
         Lectura_Reader["Nombre"].ToString(),
         Lectura_Reader["Codigo"].ToString(),
         IMAGEN AQUI
    }));
}
```

Alguien me podria explicar que debo corregir.

Gracias

Comment: Hola que tal, podrias explicar que es lo que contiene tu lista en la parte de la imagen??

Comment: Realmente no he sabido que colocar allí, he colocado solamente "image1" como llamo a mi ImageList, pero no funciona porque me dice que "no se puede convertir ImageList es String" y si le pongo "image1.ToString()" me trae una serie de propiedades del objeto pero no la imagen como tal.